# How do I create a Rails migration that updates a foreign key with an on-delete cascade constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-keys, migration, constraints, cascade

I’m using Rails 4.2.3 and a PostgreSQL database.  I want to write a migration to update one of my foreign keys to have an on-delete cascade constraint, so I created the following:

```
class UpdateForeignKeyAddOnDeleteConstraint < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :my_object_times, :my_objects
    add_foreign_key :my_object_times, :my_objects, on_delete: cascade
  end
end
```

but when I run the migration I get the error below:

```
$ rake db:migrate
== 20160525203028 UpdateForeignKeyAddOnDeleteConstraint: migrating ============
-- remove_foreign_key(:my_object_times, :my_objects)
   -> 0.0454s
-- cascade()
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined local variable or method `cascade' for #<UpdateForeignKeyAddOnDeleteConstraint:0x007f82f2c71998>
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:664:in `block in method_missing'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
```

How am I supposed to write my migration to update the foreign key?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to change this line,

```
add_foreign_key :my_object_times, :my_objects, on_delete: cascade
```

With this one:

```
add_foreign_key :my_object_times, :my_objects, on_delete: :cascade
```

The simple difference is that `cascade` should be a symbol (`:cascade`) or a string (`'cascade'`).

See the [documentation on add_foreign_key](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/add_foreign_key) for more info.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I used `add_reference :books, :author, type: :uuid, foreign_key: true` to associate that a book belongs_to and author.  When I try to delete an author though, I get an foreign key constraint error.  In my Rails code I have added `dependent: :destroy` to the author, but I'd like that to be reflected in the schema.  Should I remove the foreign key: true and add an add_foreign_key call?  Any suggestions on best practice?

Comment: Hi Jeffrey. I suggest that you have a look here on stack overflow regarding the subject (here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+dependent+destroy+not+working). If you still can't find your answer I suggest opening a new question here on StackOverflow. People will most likely want code samples and reproduction to help you solve it, and the comments track isn't really good for that.